# Populating combobox on userform from dynamic sql results

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, adodb, recordset

I have a simple userform with 2 comboboxes. The first contains a choice of 2 SQL servers. The second should contain a list of databases from the chosen server populated by a query - this does not currently work.

I can copy the data from the recordset to a sheet in my workbook but not into the combobox.

Previously I have filled the comboboxes by looping through values on a xlveryhidden sheet with no problem:

```
For i = 1 to i = LastRow
UserForm1.ComboBox2.AddItem Range("A" & i)
next i
```

This is my attempt at copying the data from the recordset so far:

```
Dim i As Integer
Do Until i = rst.RecordCount
UserForm1.ComboBox2.AddItem rst.getrows(1, i)
i = i + 1
Loop
```

This is getting a type mismatch error. Not sure if I'm on the right track.

Does anyone know how to populate the combobox with results from a sql query lying in a recordset? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any need to loop:

```
If Not rst.EOF then Me.ComboBox2.Column = rst.getrows()
```

should be enough to put the whole recordset into the control. GetRows returns an array transposed from the way you might expect, which is why I used .Column and not .List